# Came out on/onto the roof

Tags: prepositions

Mia came out on/onto the roof.

Which one of "on" and "onto" is the correct preposition to use here? Is there a more natural to write the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever there is some kind of **movement** or **change in place** use **onto.**

So here:

> "Mia came out **onto** the roof."

Is correct.

However, without context the question seems to be kind of *ambiguous.*

Comment: This is true and "onto" is correct, but "came out on the roof" is so widely used that it would not be thought an error by most.